# Cite references in figure caption

Tags: graphics, captions, citing, apa-style

**Problem:**

Getting error messages when trying to cite a reference in the figure caption. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can't seem to find that this has been up previously either.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{rub14,
   author = {Rubin, Jared},
   title = {Printing and {Protestants}: An empirical test of the role of printing in the {Reformation}},
   journal = {Review of Economics and Statistics},
   volume = {96},
   number = {2},
   pages = {270--286},
   year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{conceptdriven.eps}
\caption{\label{fig:researchscope}The process of concept-driven design approach in relation to theory and use situation, adopted from \citeA[p.~282]{rub14}} 
\end{figure}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

**Desired outcome:**

The reference to be directly after the words "adopted from".

Comment: Try using the optional argument of caption. btw, except for the figure, this is a very very good mwe.

Comment: @Johannes_B Tried the notoccite on the MWE but did not work. Any suggestions regarding the optional argument?

Comment: For lacking a better example [REMOVE or KEEP the reference in the list of figures page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/536677)

Comment: @Johannes_B Works like a charm, you saved my evening. Very grateful!

Comment: An alternative is to use `\protect` in front of `\citeA`, i.e., `\protect\citeA{...}`. The `\label` command should not be in the scope of the `\caption` command. Thus it should be `\caption{....}\label{....}`.

Comment: You can also put the cite into a savebox.

Comment: Off-topic: Unless the TeX distribution in use is positively ancient (say, from before 2012), it should not be necessary to (a) load the `epstopdf` package or (b) specify the option `pdftex` when loading the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The macro `\citeA` is "fragile", in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word. If it occurs inside a "moving argument" (more LaTeX jargon, sorry), such as the argument of a `\caption` instruction, one must prefix a `\protect` instruction:

```
\caption{\label{fig:researchscope}The process of concept-driven 
  design approach in relation to theory and use situation, 
  adopted from \protect\citeA[p.~282]{rub14}}
```

For another example of this type, see the posting [Using \input{} inside caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207905/5001).

Comment: The 10th upvote of this answer, received on 20 June 2017, earned me not only a "Nice Answer" badge but also my 888th [!] badge overall on this site. Many thanks!!!

Comment: The 25th upvote of this answer, received on 17 May 2019, earned me not only a silver "Good Answer" badge but also the 1220th badge overall on this site. Many thanks!!!

Comment: The 40th upvote of this answer, received on 12 October 2021, earned me the 38th silver "Guru" badge (and 1,728th badge overall) on this site. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

There is a similar question in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487728/latex-inserting-a-reference-in-a-figures-caption).

The problem with the `\cite` command in the figure caption is that it generates conflicts with the automatic creation of the *List of Figures*. So the first option is to put an alternative caption into brackets:

```
\caption[test caption]{test caption from~\cite{MyCite}}
```

You can also use the `\protect` environnement as suggested in the comments:

```
\caption{test caption from~\protect\cite{MyCite}}
```

As for your minimal working example, you could do it as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \graphicspath{{figures/}}

  \usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

  \usepackage{apacite}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}

  \usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{rub14,
     author = {Rubin, Jared},
     title = {Printing and {Protestants}: An empirical test of the role of printing in the {Reformation}},
     journal = {Review of Economics and Statistics},
     volume = {96},
     number = {2},
     pages = {270--286},
     year = {2014},
  }
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{document}
    \listoffigures

    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \lipsum[3]
    \begin{figure}[htp]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{sample_pic}%
      %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{conceptdriven.eps}
      \caption[The process of concept-driven design approach in relation to theory and use situation]{The process of concept-driven design approach in relation to theory and use situation, adopted from~\citeA[p.~282} 
      \label{fig:researchscope}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[2]
    \bibliography{\jobname}

   \end{document}
```

And the output would look like:

[image: Output for MWE]

Comment: What advice would you give if the optional argument of `\caption` needs to be a bit more informative than just "test".

Comment: @Mico Just changed that in the MWE. I would simply put the same caption in the brackets without the reference: `\caption[This is the caption of my figure]{This is the caption of my figure~\cite{JSmith}}`. In this way, in the figure you would have the citation, but not in the list of figures (where it's useless).

Comment: @Mico I added the *List of Figures* to the MWE to emphasize the difference.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that this solution is the only one that works if you're in the situation where you have to cite multiple references a la `<\cite{x, y}>`. For some reason, `<\protect>` can't seem to handle it.