# Overleaf \begin{document} is missing, probably bibliography error

Tags: bibliographies

I have a, to me, confusing LaTeX error: The compiler says that my document is missing the `\begin{document}`  instruction, but of course it is not missing at all. This is the error message:

> No \begin{document} command was found. Make sure you have included \begin{document} in your preamble, and that your main document is set correctly.
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.
> ...
> l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{}
> .You're in trouble here.  Try typing    to proceed.
> If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

The Overleaf-help states this can happen if you do not include the `\documentclass[]{}` instruction but i have included as well. This error started to appear after in put a new source in my bibliography, that is why i believe the bibliography is the real problem. I use Jabref for managing my bibliography and I manually include the information needed for the source in Jabref, I do not automatically import stuff. One source seems to cause problems as Jabref always tells me that the information was changed by a different programm and i should check if I want to save the changes (of course nothing changed).

Here is the preamble of my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\linespread{1.5} % Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\lstset{language=c++,
    frame=top, frame=bottom,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    tabsize = 4,
    showstringspaces = false,
    keywordstyle =\color{dkblue},
    stringstyle = \color{red},
    commentstyle = \color{dkgreen}
}
\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = darkgray,
urlcolor = blue,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = blue] {hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bachelor.bib}

\begin{document}
```

Note: the bibliography uses bibtex style. I do not know if that causes a problem with the APA style I am forced to use. I do not use any other .tex files, just the main document and the .bib file.

Answer (score 7):

`\bibliography{filename}` (the `.bib` is not required I believe) actually prints out the bibliography to the output, so has to be placed *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I use the ```\printbibliography``` command at the end of the document, but before the ```\end{document}``` instruction. I use glossaries and as far as I know they the ```\makeglossaries``` instruction need to be the last before ```\begin{document}```. 

I did your solution and placed the ```\bibliography{filename}``` rght after the ```\begin{document}``` instruction (with and without the extension), but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @LilianKorba `\printbibliography` is from the package `biblatex`. You're not using `biblatex` as far as I can see, so `\bibliography` has to be inside the `document` environment.

Comment: @LilianKorba After moving `\bibliography`, try recompiling from scratch. (click the arrow next to the compile button -> bottom of the drop down menu). You also need to cite something from the bibliography (with e.g. `\cite{foo}`) for the bibliography to appear, have you done that?

Comment: I included ```\usepacke{biblatex}``` into the preamble and moved the ```\bibliographystyle{apacite}``` and ```\bibliography{bachelor.bib}``` to the end of the document but before ```\appendix```. I tried to recompile but Overleaf still cannot produce a PDF file. I watched an Overleaf tutorial and for the apacite package the instruction ```\printbibliography``` does not seem to be necessary.

I found something interesting: apacite is not compatible with biblatex, according to the compiler. When i remove the ```\usepackage{biblatex}``` instruction, the compiler marks a figure as error....

Comment: ``` \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{duolingo_links.jpeg}
        \caption{Gebrauch von Gamification-Elementen bei DuoLingo (Teil 1) \cite{lingobild}}
        \label{fig:duolingo1}
    \end{figure}```

The line with the caption is considered faulty. The compiler says: 
>Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@. Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. Runaway argument?

Comment: @LilianKorba Looks like you forgot the closing `}` of `\caption{}`. Back to the bibliography stuff, if you use biblatex` then you use `\addbibresource{filename.bib}` in the preamble and `\printbibliography` where you want to add the bibliography. If not (which is your case), you add `\bibligraphystyle{foo} \bibliography{filename}` where you want to add the bibliography, and do not include `\printbibliography`.

Comment: but where did i forgot a { ? I have no idea what Overleaf means by ```\caption@ydblarg```. I dont see a missing bracket in the caption line.

Comment: @LilianKorba Sorry, my bad, I misread. Try `\protect\cite...` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227839/586

Comment: no problem at all. the ```\protect\cite{}``` helped solve it a bit. Now Overleaf says something else: now it says in that caption line: ``` Argument of \@@cite has an extra }. Runaway argument?``` Overleaf says this for all citations now, also those which are not on figures. I dont know why he says @@

Comment: @LilianKorba I think `\@@cite` is an "internal" macro that `\cite` uses. But I don't know what happens, I suggest you post a new question where you include a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the error. By "minimal and complete" I mean a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that reproduces the error, but one that includes only the necessary parts to do so (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/ for some more on such MWEs -- minimal working examples).

Comment: Okay i will do that. Thank you very much for your help!