# \input{} inside \chemfig{}

Tags: tables, environments, input, chemfig, protected-macro

I'm likely ignoring something fundamental here and was hoping for some hints.  Please see the inset mwe.

Towards having a library of chemfig symbols, I see value in being able to point to a particular symbol (stored in an external .tex file) via the `\input{}` command, the obvious construct being: `\chemfig[][]{\input{<chemfig symbol library path>/{<symbol name>}}}`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=7pt,active,tightpage]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

%\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
%H% 2
%    -[:210]% 1
%              (
%        -[:210]H% 3
%              )
%              (
%        -[:300]H% 5
%              )
%    -[:120]H% 4
%\end{filecontents}

% representation without comments
\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
H
    -[:210]
              (
        -[:210]H
              )
              (
        -[:300]H
              )
    -[:120]H
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\robustinputcommand}{\input{methane.tex}}

% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formulae
\def\methane{\mathrm{CH_{4}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[]{lp{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure}\\
\midrule%
%$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}[]{1cm} \chemfig{\input{methane.tex}} \end{minipage} \\ [2mm]% gives error
%$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}[]{1cm} \chemfig{\protect\input{methane.tex}} \end{minipage} \\ [2mm]% gives error
%$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}[]{1cm} \chemfig{\robustinputcommand} \end{minipage} \\ [2mm]% gives error
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error I observe consistently:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<everyeof> \_nil
```

I have tried a few approaches, particularly those described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207905/using-input-inside-caption).  These are commented in the mwe.

Note that the construct: `\input{<full file path>}` (document level call) and `\chemfig[][]{<content defining symbol>}` (generic structure of external document) works fine, but this does not immediately allow one to apply formatting e.g. `[scale=0.5]` as optional argument of `\chemfig` at the document level - something there is clear value in being able to do.

Comment: Maybe consider using chemfig's submol mechanism instead. In this way, you can keep multiple molecules in the same library file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `\chemfiginput` command that also accepts the optional argument like `\chemfig`.

```latex
% representation without comments
\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
H
    -[:210]
              (
        -[:210]H
              )
              (
        -[:300]H
              )
    -[:120]H
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{catchfile}


% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formulae
\newcommand\methane{\ensuremath{\mathrm{CH_{4}}}}

\newcommand{\chemfiginput}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\chemfiginputtemp}{#2}{\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\chemfigdo\expandafter{\chemfiginputtemp}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\chemfigdo}[2]{\chemfig[#2]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure}\\
\midrule
\methane & \chemfiginput{methane} \\
\methane & \chemfiginput[chemfig style={color=red!40!black, line width=1.5pt}]{methane} \\
\methane & \chemfig{H-[:210](-[:210]H)(-[:300]H)-[:120]H} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one is nice and simple, easy to deploy.  A few follow-up questions.  Passing the option `chemfig style={scale=0.5}` does not seem to scale the chemfig object, how do I do this?  Also, what's a nice way to vertically center the chemfig object with the text in the row?

Comment: @JohnChris No idea for both, sorry. Open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Including `\chemfig{` and `}` into the `methane.tex` instead of surrounding the `\input` command with it aparently seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=7pt,active,tightpage]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
\chemfig{
H
    -[:210]
              (
        -[:210]H
              )
              (
        -[:300]H
              )
    -[:120]H}
\end{filecontents}


% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formulae
\def\methane{$\mathrm{CH_{4}}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure}\\
\midrule
\methane & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\input{methane.tex}}\\ [2mm]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The final paragraph of the original question alludes to this solution.  What if you wanted to scale the symbol, apply any tikz formatting? make the graphic/symbol have white lines on a dark background?  I think the most elegant arrangement is not to have the `\chemfig{}` call in the external symbol definition.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part about removing the `\chemfig` call from the external `.tex` files is that it changes the category codes before reading its mandatory argument. In order to cope with this, I use `\CatchFileDef` from the `catchfile` package to save the contents of `methane.tex` with the same category code setup as used by `\chemfig`.

The code below is generic and can be used with no effort for other molecules. Ti*k*Z options for molecule structure printing can be specified in a central place (`\myprintmol`) and there is no redundancy in the `tabular`: just separate the molecule names with commas:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}              % for \newcolumntype
\usepackage{collcell}           % for \collectcell
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{catchfile}          % for \CatchFileDef
\usepackage{adjustbox}          % for \adjustbox
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % for \forcsvlist

% cf. <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98011/73317> (Ulrike Fischer)
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathup}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\newcommand*{\mydeclaremolstruct}[1]{%
  \expandafter\CatchFileDef\expandafter{\csname #1struct\endcsname}{#1.tex}%
     {\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
}

\newcommand*{\myprintmol}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % Here, you can customize how molecule structure is printed (TikZ options)
  \setchemfig{chemfig style={color=red!40!black, line width=1.5pt}}%
  %
  \adjustbox{valign=M}{% To align with vertical center of the whole molecule
    \expandafter\chemfig\expandafter{#1}% Process tokenized contents from
  }%                                    % external per-molecule .tex files
  \endgroup
}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
H
    -[:210]
              (
        -[:210]H
              )
              (
        -[:300]H
              )
    -[:120]H
\end{filecontents}

\mydeclaremolstruct{methane}    % base name of the corresponding .tex file
\newcommand*{\methane}{\mathup{CH}_{4}}

% Special column type for representing the molecule structure
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\myprintmol}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand*{\generatetableline}[1]{%
  $\csname #1\endcsname$ & \csname #1struct\endcsname \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lM}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Structure}}\\
\midrule
\forcsvlist{\generatetableline}{methane}%
%\forcsvlist{\generatetableline}{methane, ethane, propane}%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the same slightly simplified, but also slightly less automatic for the table construction:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}              % for \newcolumntype
\usepackage{collcell}           % for \collectcell
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{catchfile}          % for \CatchFileDef
\usepackage{adjustbox}          % for \adjustbox

% cf. <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98011/73317> (Ulrike Fischer)
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathup}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\newcommand*{\mydeclaremolstruct}[1]{%
  \expandafter\CatchFileDef\expandafter{\csname #1struct\endcsname}{#1.tex}%
     {\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
}

\newcommand*{\myprintmol}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % Here, you can customize how molecule structure is printed (TikZ options)
  \setchemfig{chemfig style={color=red!40!black, line width=1.5pt}}%
  %
  \adjustbox{valign=M}{% To align with vertical center of the whole molecule
    \expandafter\chemfig\expandafter{#1}% Process tokenized contents from
  }%                                    % external per-molecule .tex files
  \endgroup
}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
H
    -[:210]
              (
        -[:210]H
              )
              (
        -[:300]H
              )
    -[:120]H
\end{filecontents}

\mydeclaremolstruct{methane}    % base name of the corresponding .tex file
\newcommand*{\methane}{\mathup{CH}_{4}}

% Special column type for representing the molecule structure
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\myprintmol}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}M}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Structure}}\\
\midrule
\methane & \methanestruct \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(same output as in the previous screenshot).

Comment: I love where this solution has been taken and the functionality it suggests.  For the sake of simplicity, would it make sense to subtract some of the advanced features such as: combining formula and structure and support for multiple compounds?

Comment: My last edit added a slightly simplified solution (which is also less automatic). In this solution, each table line has to be entered like ``\methane & \methanestruct \\`` .