# Using \input{} in inline mathmode -- extra `}`

Tags: math-mode, input

I generate certain values and print them in single .tex-files (`example.tex`) in python, mostly in the form `\SI{<value>}{\percent}` or as single lines for tabular environments `& \SI{<value>}{\percent} & \SI{<value>}{\percent} & \SI{<value>}{\percent}`.

However, I can easily use `\input{example.tex}` to include this value in normal text,`align` or `tabular` environments without any trouble. But when using it within a mathmode (`$$`, `\[\]`, `\ensuremath`) of a table caption, the log files yields "...an extra `}`" at the place of input.

Pdflatex compiles and the value shows up, bit since the warning is an error, Id like to ask either:

```
1) Is the use of `\input{}` for this purpose generally recommended?
2) How to get rid of the error/what did I do wrong?
```

Below an MWE, `test_size.tex` consists purely of `\SI{30}{\percent}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
    Normal inline mode works: \input{./values/test_size.tex}\\[1ex]
    Normal math inline mode works: $\input{./values/test_size.tex}$
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Math inline caption doesnt work: $\input{./values/test_size.tex}$}
    \end{table}
    \begin{align}
        \textrm{align enviroment works: } \input{./values/test_size.tex}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207917/142945) would have helped as well. Sorry for double posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\input` is an endangered species, it needs protection, use `\protect\input` instead.

Though, why would you include data like this in the first place?

Comment: Cheers. Ive never spent much thought about why not or what else. I used `\input` to include different sections and so far for me it is the easiest way to automatically use values generated in my python projects.
I assume there are better ways, and eager to read up on it. Could you provide me with some keywords?

Comment: That sees overly complicated. But ok, you do you, I'd probably make a macro such that you could just use `\ExtVal{test_size}` instead of writing this all the time. Then it is also much easier if you later on decide to move the data to a different folder.

Comment: Ah alright. I thought there are some other, more common ways without using `\input` in the first place. But sure, macros shorten my effort as well.

Comment: External data can be inputted in many ways it all depends on how you are able to prepare the data. It should be a CSV file. It could a a latex file defining some data structures that can then be  outputtet using an interface like I descibed above (having everything in just one file saves a lot of IO).

Comment: Could be, not should be